# Get total files uploaded in filestack account

Tags: javascript, php, filepicker

I'm using filestack API using trail account in applications which allows 250 files to be uploaded, is it possible to get count of total files uploaded? because I want to perform alternative method if upload count is exceeded? How can I check count is exceeded?

Comment: can anyone explain why negative vote for this?

Comment: what did you try so far ? show us some code

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for a way to do this programmatically or are you just looking for your monthly usage?

Filestack provides rudimentary stats for each apikey in the Dashboard portion of the dev portal. You have to select the apikey you're interested in and then navigate to the dashboard.

(Attached is what [Filestack's apikey stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdyfJ.png) look like but I don't have any usage on this key, if I had usage there would be a bar graph and #'s.)

You'll also receive emails from the FS team when you get close to your limit and they'll shut your key off when you hit 100% of any of the limits*.

*edited to add: your free key, they'll shut your free key off. they don't shut off paid keys for hitting limits.

Comment: i have to do this programatically, get total files uploaded so far

Comment: so, what have you tried already?

Also, the file upload [limit resets monthly](https://www.filestack.com/pricing/free) for Filestack free plans. The only limit that doesn't reset is storage.